# Selector Drawable programmatically

Tags: java, android, drawable

I want to create selector drawables programmatically. The shape has to be in the following form:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><shape>
            <solid android:color="#4aa5d4" />
        </shape></item>
    <item><shape>
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#4aa5d4" />
        </shape></item>

</selector>
```

Why? Because i want those 2 colors the be changeable. I know i have to create some kind of `Drawable` for this. I already managed to create my own `GradientDrawables` like this:

```
public GradientDrawable getBackgroundGradient() {
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] { BACKGROUND_GRADIENT_TOP_COLOR, BACKGROUND_GRADIENT_BOTTOM_COLOR });
    return gd;
}
```

But now I need a SelectorDrawable.

Comment: OK, thank you. I think i can do something with that ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, here is, what i came up with using the linked topic.

```
public StateListDrawable getSelectorDrawable(int color) {
    StateListDrawable out = new StateListDrawable();
    out.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_pressed }, createNormalDrawable(color));
    out.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, createStrokeDrawable(color));
    return out;
}

public GradientDrawable createNormalDrawable(int color) {
    GradientDrawable out = new GradientDrawable();
    out.setColor(color);
    return out;
}

public GradientDrawable createStrokeDrawable(int color) {
    GradientDrawable out = new GradientDrawable();
    out.setStroke(1, color);
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just supply a drawable as the resource in your Selector XML.  The drawable can be anything (PNG, XML, etc)

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/shape_highlighted"
        android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/shape_disabled"
        android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/shape_normal"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: But then i'd have to change that given Drawable Ressource, which is not possible, as far as im aware?

Comment: If you want to change a particular color, just change the entire Selector (ie. provide a different selector with a different drawable for the state you need to change).  I am not sure you will be able to change a particular state drawable using Java.

Comment: Got it all solved, the way i wanted it to be. See my own answer ;)